# How do i force a resolution on a monitor that doesn't support it

Tags: graphics-card, display

Is it possible to force your computer/monitor to display a higher resolution then what's supported by the monitor? I have a 1600x900 monitor and i want 1080p at the very least. Is it possible for me to get 1080p? What do i have to do? I have a GTX 780 and intel i7.

Comment: Sorry, but why? It will definitely crop off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a GTX 780. Go to the desktop, right click and click NVIDIA Control Panel. When you're at the Control Panel, click "Adjust desktop size and position". There should be an option called "Perform scaling on", change the setting to : "GPU". and then click on OK, after that, hit Customize, check the box that says "Enable resolutions not supported by the display" and click "Create Custom Resolution". From there, you want to set horizontal pixels as 1920 and vertical pixels as 1080. Click OK and you should have a 1080p resolution.

Comment: i tried it and it works, thank you so much man! now i can play minecraft in super awesome 1080p